# How to view and edit mounted gdrive files in gspread format without authentication on google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, gspread

I have mounted the google drive using the in-built function on google colab.

According to google, this means that the files should act as if they were accessible and editable from the local directory.

However, `file = open("file path", "r+")` leads to "AttributeError: module 'gspread' has no attribute 'open'".

How do you open and edit these gspread files without further authentication beyond the automatic authentication of mounting gspread (i.e, not using the gc.open_by_url() approach)?